# Hide status bar on iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, statusbar

In my application, for a particular screen, I need to hide the status bar. My screen hierarchy is:

```
MainScreen -> ScreenA -> ScreenB -> Screenc
```

In My **Screenc** I need to hide the status bar. So I am doing like this:

```
 override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
```

It's working fine. But when I push back from `Screenc` my `ScreenB, ScreenA` status bar and my nav bar are overlapping. Like my `ScreenB, ScreenA` `title`, `right bar button`, and all overlap with status bar. But my status bar is also showing in `ScreenB, ScreenA`.

Not sure why it's happening. In my plist file I have :

```
View controller-based status bar appearance : YES
```

I can't change this to NO. Because in my application I am using fixing portrait to particular viewcontroller.

Any solution to how can I fix these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to show and hide in Appear and Disappear

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    }
```

Comment: may i know the differance btw `navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden` and `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden`. When i was doing this hidden `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden` its not working

Comment: `isNavigationBarHidden` base is `UIViewController` while `isHidden` base is `UIView`

Comment: Just to understand, why `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden` doesn;t work well . But its hides the nav bar. When i move back, my nav bar moves up.Is there any problem happening when i hide my both nav bar and status bar.

Comment: dont know much about that .. you can post this specific question ...

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidLoad() function add

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

And in your previous ViewController on viewDidAppear method add

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
```

Comment: Its already hiding in my current vc. But when i go back my previous screen status bar and nav bar is mess up. This vc is in my navigation controller stack

Comment: In my current VC, i am hiding nav bar. But when i go back in my previous screen my nav bar and status bar mess up

Comment: in my previous screen i can able to see the nav bar and status bar. But both are overlapped. Like one another one ....I first did one by one. First i hide the nav bar and un hide the nav bar..its working fine..no over lap issues. But if i hide my status bar then i am getting that overlap issues